# datanode runs but not detected

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I configured hadoop on 2 machine. everything works fine. In the first one if I run the command `jps` I have

```
16406 NameNode
16774 ResourceManager
16619 SecondaryNameNode
17037 Jps
```

And in the second machine I have

```
2641 Jps
2445 NodeManager
2141 DataNode
```

but if I go in the browser master:50070 I see `Live DataNodes 0`(why?)
in fact if I try to put a file (`hdfs dfs -put /input/file.txt`)
I get this error

```
15/03/08 01:43:25 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/03/08 01:43:26 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /input/file.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1549)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:641)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1399)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:588)
put: File /input/reduced.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

Why it say me that there are no datanodes? 
Instead if I run the command `hdfs dfs -mkdir /input` it works, why it behaves differently?

Comment: Probably, your datanode can't connect to the namenode. Please, provide logs for the datanode and the namenode. When you create the directory, only metadata about it are stored on the namenode. That's why this operation works.

Answer (score 1):

Your datanode is not able to connect to Namenode that is the reason for your datanode not being reflected namenode web UI. Please update the core-site.xml file present in both nodes along with datanode log.

Your core-site should have namenode address.

```
<property>       
 <name>fs.default.name</name>       
 <value>hdfs://$namenode.full.hostname:8020</value>  
 <description>Enter your NameNode hostname</description>
</property>
```

Comment: Can you specify which property must be updated in core-site.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is in your hostname only. Use FULL COMPUTER NAME instead of hostname. If your system connected with a domain then you have to specify FCN which likes **hostname.domainname**

Then use FCN in all hadoop configuration files. FCN should be access/ping from all other machines. If you cannot ping it. Then edit /etc/hosts file and set the FCN for the specific ip address.

Some of the hadoop configuration to be set with FCN are listed below.

**Core-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://FCN:8020</value>
</property>
```

**Hdfs-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>FCN:50070</value>
</property>
```

Let me know if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Fixed it by ensuring all the slaves has "etc\hosts" file updated with the current ip.